# WCFTransaction Exception

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, transactions

I am currently working on client-service architecture using WCF, c# .NET. I was stuck with well-known transaction exception for this architecture while running client and server on different machines (No problem if both on same machine). By searching on web, I resolved this issue with MSDTC settings as well as Firewall settings as shown on this link: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/how-configure-msdtc-and-firewall-distributed-wcf-service. I made outbound settings enable on client and inbound settings enabled on server. Also set exception for DTC on client side. Now that problem is partially resolved at the cost of serious issue. When I run the app, sometime it throws exception but sometimes suddenly runs successfully w/o changing anything. I am totally clueless, what is wrong in this case. Any idea?

Comment: What exception you are seeing. A little log or even exception message would not hurt.

Comment: @Chaturvedi: Exception is "The flowed transaction could not be unmarshaled. The following exception occurred. Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed"

Comment: I simply googled your error message and found this http://offroadcoder.com/the-flowed-transaction-could-not-be-unmarshaled/